# Project Euler problem 18 cant reach to the last element

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'am trying to solve Project Euler problem 18 with these algorithm, adding the first line to the second and make sure we find the bigger value
of each one by replacing the original value with new one.

I know my code is not reaching the last element on each row, but how can I fix it?

(Problem description: find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle, choosing one number from each row, moving to an adjascent number each time.)

#### Attempt

```
public static void main(String args[])  {

    int number[][] = {
            {75},
            {95,64},
            {17,47,82},
            {18,35,87,10},
            {20,04,82,47,65},
            {19,01,23,75,03,34},
            {88,02,77,73,07,63,67},
            {99,65,04,28,06,16,70,92},
            {41,41,26,56,83,40,80,70,33},
            {41,48,72,33,47,32,37,16,94,29},
            {53,71,44,65,25,43,91,52,97,51,14},
            {70,11,33,28,77,73,17,78,39,68,17,57},
            {91,71,52,38,17,14,91,43,58,50,27,29,48},
            {63,66,04,68,89,53,67,30,73,16,69,87,40,31},
            {04,62,98,27,23,9,70,98,73,93,38,53,60,04,23}};

    for(int i = 1 ; i < number.length ; i++ ) 
        for(int j = 0 , k = 0 ; j <= i+1 ; k++,j++) {
        // k is the number of term in previous array
                if(k < number[i-1].length) {
                    
                    // if the first term 
                    if(k == 0) {
                        // if the the k is the only number in the array >(when i = 0)
                        if (number[i-1].length == 1)
                    
                // add it to down value
                            number[i][j] += number[i-1][k];
                        else {
                            //then if we have 2 k add the bigger k to down  value
                            if(number[i-1][k+1]  > number[i-1][k])
                            number[i][j] += number[i-1][k+1];
                            else
                            number[i][j] += number[i-1][k];
                        }
                    }
                    // if k in the mid
                else if( k > 0 && k < number[i-1].length - 1) {
                    //add the bigger value to down term
                    if (number[i-1][k] < number[i-1][k+1] && number[i-1][k] < number[i-1][k-1] )
                        number[i][j] += number[i-1][k];
                    else if( number[i-1][k+1] > number[i-1][k-1] )
                        number[i][j] += number[i-1][k+1];
                    else
                        number[i][j] += number[i-1][k-1];
                }
                else {
                    // if the we reach last k 
                    if(number[i-1][k] > number[i-1][k-1])
                        number[i][j] += number[i-1][k];
                    else
                        number[i][j] += number[i-1][k-1];
                }
        
                }
        }
        
        
    int x = 3;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < number[x].length ; i++ )
    System.out.print(number[x][i] + " ");
    

}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of the Euler problem to your question. However, you really should not be asking for help for any Euler problem--that goes against the philosophy of Project Euler.

Comment: @RoryDaulton please quote and link where Project Euler says someone should not ask for help.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: [The About page for Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/about) is one such place. See, for example, the section "I solved it by using a search engine, does that matter?"

Comment: @RoryDaulton I could find neither the word, "search," nor the word, "engine," in the page you linked to. (I'm on a mobile phone, not sure if that matters.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן: It's the fourth section down, between the sections "Does it matter if it takes more than one minute to solve?" and "I've checked my program ten times now and I keep getting told my answer is wrong! Have you made a mistake?" I suppose it is possible that I am seeing a different page than you are seeing. The mobile phone may be causing that.

Comment: @RoryDaulton ah, you need to be logged in to see the things you mentioned on the About page. I can't find anything about not asking for help on it, though. Could you please point me to it? The section with "search engine" that you mentioned, to me, seems to be referring to copying the actual answer, not seeking help on how to solve it.

Comment: I'm not looking for the solution .. i'm asking for  coding help

Comment: It looked to me like you are capable of coding loops and choices based on comparing numbers. The idea I posted in my answer was meant to address your question: how to reach the last element on each row.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint related to your algorithm: imagine the triangle were upside down, with the tip on the bottom and the base on top. Consider that the best path here, although directed in the description, can be traced in either direction for our purposes.

> We start at the bottom, knowing that one of the cells there was the final cell in the best path. Every pair of cells on the bottom row had only one parent. We choose the greater of the pair and add it to the parent above. Follow this procedure through each line to the top.

Comment: My answer above was meant to address the OP's question: how to reach the last element on each row.